# Matplotlib errorbar scaled by a factor in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am plotting data from a CSV file named test.csv that has the values like:

```
X                      Y            Yerrmin              Yerrmax
13.629119553139 0.13237415706937    0.115879894547257   0.14748971609137
55.3872849395824    0.14385506424916    0.13237415706937    0.153752686711682
208.442201941724    0.144454558978827   0.129650059586552   0.158954011478447
544.589674426085    0.151216201294351   0.13515549098632    0.168483298334671
968.990798410664    0.149341335862913   0.135718731529535   0.164331292710806
1305.01533678836    0.146268074690858   0.13073290613871    0.162970154348788
1596.62602210143    0.14748971609137    0.13292580681435    0.165016119097793
```

In my code, I have:

```
testK = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=",", names=["X", "Y", "Yerrmin", "Yerrmax"])
testK_yerr=[testK['Yerrmin'], testK['Yerrmax']]
plt.errorbar(testK['X'], testK['Y'], yerr=testK_yerr, fmt='sk')
plt.savefig("test_plot.pdf")
```

This gives the plot: [image: plot with errorbar]

I cannot find the problem why the error bars are scaled by a multiplicative factor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Yerrmin values should be the amount less than the data point that you want the error bar to extend down to. So as your first Y point is 0.13 the Y error will extend down to 0.13-0.12 = 0.01, which is where it is. If Yerrmin is actually the minimum Y value, i.e. you want the error band to extend from 0.115 to 0.147 then you need to make make new values to pass to the function like

```
testK_yerr=[testk['Y']-testK['Yerrmin'], testK['Yerrmax']-testK['Y']]
```

and pass those instead

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that ```yerr``` does not accept absolute value rather it calculates the difference from the ```y``` value.